# SonarQube WebApi Access File Source Code

Tags: sonarqube

It looks like the sonar web api changed in the last days. At least one of my projects using the api isn't working anymore.

I specifically need to access the source code of components / files.

According to the online doc (http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743288) this should be possible with a call like 'http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/sources?resource=org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-plugin-api:org.sonar.api.measures.CoreMetrics' what isn't working anymore.

Can anybody tell me how to access the source code of a file via the current sonar web api? Help would be very appreciated.

Thanks and best regards,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API hasn't changed. But the key of components has changed in SonarQube 4.2. I updated the example on http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743288